# Replacing values in an array

Tags: php

I need to add a `<p>` tag to the beginning of each array value and a closing `</p>` tag at the end of each array value.

If there is a `[` or `]` delimiter then they need to be replaced with `<p class="myclass">`

```
Array
(
    [0] => [This is a line of text
    [1] => and another
    [2] => and yet another.] [This is another line of text
    [3] => and another
    [4] => and another] [OK, so you get the idea.
)
```

The above array should become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p class="myclass">This is a line of text</p>
    [1] => <p>and another</p>
    [2] => <p>and yet another.</p> <p class="myclass">This is another line of text</p>
    [3] => <p>and another</p>
    [4] => <p>and another</p> <p class="myclass">OK, so you get the idea.</p>
)
```

The question is: Using a foreach loop, how do I get from the first array to the second array?

Comment: your question is very confusing, what exactly do you wanna do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  $array[$i] = '<p>'.$array[$i].'</p>';
  $array[$i] = preg_replace('/\]/', '</p>', $array[$i]);
  $array[$i] = preg_replace('/\[/', '<p class="myclass">', $array[$i]);
  $array[$i] = preg_replace('/<p><p/', '<p', $array[$i]);
}
```

[See Live Example](http://codepad.org/aCmjv5HU)

Comment: thank you! This works perfect. I was having a hard time getting this to work just right.

Answer (score 3):

```
$myArray = array(
    '[This is a line of text',
    'and another',
    'and yet another.] [This is another line of text',
    'and another',
    'and another] [OK, so you get the idea.',
);

array_walk($myArray,'pTagger');

function pTagger(&$value) {
    $value = str_replace(array('[',']'),array('<p class="myClass">','</p>'),$value);
    if (substr($value,0,2) !== '<p') $value = '<p>' . $value;
    if (substr($value,-4) !== '</p>') $value .= '</p>';
}

var_dump($myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer!